# Single GUI Application raspberrypi

Tags: linux, unix, ruby, raspberry-pi, kiosk

So I want to develop a software that will take over my raspberry pi computer, or just for simplicity's sake, any computer running a lightweight linux OS, to serve a single function. Run a Ruby/Java or some other type of GUI application. I want this application to be full screen, and run instantly on bootup, and when closed, have the computer shut down.

How could I go about simplifying the Linux OS to run one application?

I intend to use this method of creation:

1. Use the recommended Linux Distro
2. Install dependencies onto distro
3. Add application, and modify, based on response to the question, so that it only runs one application
4. Create imagefile
5. Duplicate

I also might need to run a second, background process written in a different language to watch for certain messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd look into the [inittab](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?inittab+5) file. You edit it to configure what runs on bootup. Check the /etc/inittab on the distro that you use to see what is currently set up to run on your distro.

You could always run it from /etc/init.d/ and /etc/rc*.d/

One advantage to inittab is you can configure it to respawn if it crashes.

If I were you I'd migrate this to a more topic specific stackexchange site. Both [UNIX/Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) and [RaspberryPi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) specific forums exist.

Comment: How can I migrate a question?